# Angularjs advance search

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular2-directives, search-box

[image: UI]

I'm having the above user interface and when i type site name it will display all the names of the sites specifying the name which i search and i can select  the one which i want  and set the value to the text box after that i want to get the particular `siteid` to the other text box  from database by clicking the button

Site A/ Name

```
<input type='text' ng-keyup='fetchUsers()' ng-model='searchText' 
placeholder='Search Site by name'><br>
<ul id='searchResult' >
         <li ng-click='setValue($index)' ng-repeat="result in searchResult" >{{result.sitename}}</li>
</ul>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

// Fetch data
$scope.fetchUsers = function () {

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'getData.php',
        data: { searchText: $scope.searchText }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.searchResult = response.data;

    });

}

// Set value to search box
$scope.setValue = function (index) {
    $scope.searchText = $scope.searchResult[index].sitename;
    $scope.searchResult = {};

    include 'config.php';

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $search = $data ->searchText;

    $sel = mysqli_query($con, "select sitename from site where sitename like '%".$search."%' limit 5");

    $data = array();
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
        $data[] = array("sitename"=>$row['sitename']);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
}])
```

since i'm having a very basic knowledge about angularjs please help me on this

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how do i get auto fill the site id text box when i select the siteA/name

Comment: it's there in the picture(UI)